# Is there a German version of the "game" Mad Libs?

Tags: party

I am looking for a German version of the game/activity Mad Libs. I played it in English before and it was always fun. But some of my friends do not speak English well enough to participate in the game.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a German version yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Mad Libs has not been translated into German.

Also, there seems to be a similar German game named

> Onkel Otto sitzt in der Badewanne

In the German Wikipedia entry for Mad Libs, the following is stated (in German ):

> A similar game is known in Germany under the name "Uncle Otto sitting
>   in the bathtub". The English language, in which nouns, verbs and
>   adjectives are hardly inflected, offers far more favorable conditions
>   for this game than the German one.

Comment: That's too bad, but I guess it's true that the English language works a lot better for this kind of games